# FluentValidation: Mocking ValidationResult.IsValid

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation with WebAPI in DotNet core 2. I've written tests for the validator successfully, but now I'm trying to mock the validator for my controller. Controller as follows:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SecurityController : Controller {
    private readonly IValidator<AuthenticateRequest> _authenticateRequestValidator;

    public SecurityController(IValidator<AuthenticateRequest> authenticateRequestValidator) {
        _authenticateRequestValidator = authenticateRequestValidator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("auth")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody] AuthenticateRequest req) {
        // Validate
        var validator = await _authenticateRequestValidator.ValidateAsync(req);
        if(!validator.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        // ...snip
    }
}
```

AuthenticateRequest looks like this:

```
public class AuthenticateRequest {
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And the validator is as follows:

```
public class AuthenticateRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<AuthenticateRequest> {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Provides a validator for <see cref="AuthenticateRequest" />
    /// </summary>
    public AuthenticateRequestValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Username)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Username is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.Password)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Password is required");
    }
}
```

It's being injected into the controller with dot net core's standard DI. Not posting code as it's not relevant to this issue, as its a testing issue.

I'm testing with xunit, Moq and AutoFixture. Here are two tests:

```
public class SecurityControllerTests {
    private readonly IFixture Fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization {ConfigureMembers = true});

    private readonly Mock<IValidator<AuthenticateRequest>> authenticateRequestValidatorMock;

    public SecurityControllerTests() {
        authenticateRequestValidatorMock = Mock.Get(Fixture.Create<IValidator<AuthenticateRequest>>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Authenticate_ValidatesRequest() {
        // Arrange
        var request = Fixture.Create<AuthenticateRequest>();
        authenticateRequestValidatorMock
            .Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.Is<AuthenticateRequest>(v => v == request), default(CancellationToken)))
            .Returns(() => Fixture.Create<Task<ValidationResult>>())
            .Verifiable();
        var controller = new SecurityController(authenticationServiceMock.Object, tokenisationServiceMock.Object, authenticateRequestValidatorMock.Object);

        // Act
        await controller.AuthenticateAsync(request);

        // Assert
        authenticateRequestValidatorMock.Verify();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Authenticate_Returns400_WhenUsernameValidationFails() {
        // Arrange
        var request = Fixture.Create<AuthenticateRequest>();

        var validationResultMock = new Mock<ValidationResult>();
        validationResultMock
            .SetupGet(x => x.IsValid)
            .Returns(() => true);
        authenticateRequestValidatorMock
            .Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.Is<AuthenticateRequest>(v => v == request), default(CancellationToken)))
            .Returns(() => new Task<ValidationResult>(() => validationResultMock.Object));
        var controller = new SecurityController(authenticationServiceMock.Object, tokenisationServiceMock.Object, authenticateRequestValidatorMock.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.AuthenticateAsync(request);

        // Assert
        var badRequestResult = Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
        Assert.IsType<SerializableError>(badRequestResult.Value);
    }
}
```

I need to mock `ValidationResult` so I can ignore the actual validator logic (which is tested elsewhere) and test the controller logic. There are many other dependencies injected, and much more code, but the pasted code is the crux of the problem and produces the same results when everything else is stripped out.

First test passes, second runs forever when it hits the `var validator = await _authenticateRequestValidator.ValidateAsync(req);` line in the controller.

Its worth noting that ValidationResult.IsValid is a virtual readonly property.

What is wrong with the second test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Asp.Net Core - FluentValidation integration? By this way you dont need to pass Validator depedencies to constructor.

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration

FluentValidation fills ModelState in case of validation error and you use it like ;

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

For testing it you set ModelState of you Controllers Mock

```
var controller = new SecurityController(authenticationServiceMock.Object, tokenisationServiceMock.Object, authenticateRequestValidatorMock.Object);
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("test", "test");

// Act
IActionResult actionResult =  await controller.AuthenticateAsync(request);

var badRequestObjectResult = actionResult as BadRequestObjectResult;

Assert.NotNull(badRequestObjectResult);

var serializableError = badRequestObjectResult.Value as SerializableError;

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(result);
var badRequestResult = Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
var serializableError = assert.IsType<SerializableError>(badRequestResult.Value)
Assert.True(((string[])serializableError["test"])[0] == "test");
```

Leaving ModelState empty would be enough to ignore the actual validator logic i think.

Also FluentValidation have built-in testing api. You can test your validation logic separately.

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/g.-Testing

Comment: I didn't see this anywhere and it didn't come up in searches. I'll check it out and let you know. As I said, I've already written the validator logic (using the helper methods you linked) - this is mocking the validator for testing a controller.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean any harm, I have missed that you said you already wrote validation test logic. I might have been a little excited because it was my first answer to Stackoverflow :) Anyway i hope my answer will helpful.

Comment: It has certainly helped - and I believe it's the right way to go about it too. Thank you very much, marked as accepted! :)